# How can I write to the console once for every field in my list?

Tags: c#

I have a list: `deckList` and the list has a field of `name`

How can I write to the console log once for each name.  I was thinking if I could use a forEach but I am not sure how I can do this simply.

Can someone give me advice on this.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code so that we can help you.

Comment: I would but I am new to C# and .NET and so far all I have is foreach(deckList).  Can I just follow that with a block of code with Console.Writeline? But then how can I make it print the value of the field called name?

Comment: `Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, deckList.Select(d => d.name)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "console log" but since the question is tagged with C# i will assume you mean the standard console. Perhaps something like this then:

```
foreach(var deck in deckList){
    Console.WriteLine(deck.name);
}
```